# How to friend a function inside a namespace which is in a different file?

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with a friend function.
Basically I have a class in a header (inside a namespace), which contains a friend function:

```
namespace X {
class Foo {
// private members
  friend void SomeNamespace::someFunction(const Foo& foo);
}
```

And in a separate header, I have the function which I'm trying to make a friend, which is inside a namespace:

```
#include "classHeader.h"
namespace SomeNamespace {
  void someFunction(const X::Foo& foo);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, as `someFunction` can't access Foo's private members, apparently.
After some research I found out that I was missing a forward declaration, so I tried adding it:

```
namespace X{class Foo}; // Forward declare class
void SomeFunction(const X::Foo& foo);
```

But this does not seem to work either. What's wrong?

Comment: To access `Foo`s members, `SomeFunction` must have `Foo`s definition. Only forward declaring it isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But the definition should be there since I've included the header where the class is defined, no? (This wasn't shown in the example above)

Comment: When you *define* (implement) `SomeFunction` you need the full definition of the `Foo` class. Which you can get by `#include` the header file where `Foo` is defined. If you do that `#include` in the *source* file where you define `SomeFunction` you won't have a circular inclusion problem.

Comment: So, since the #include "header.h" is there, this issue is caused by circular inclusion?

Comment: For the *declaration* of `SomeFunction` you only need a forward declaration though, so in the header file which defines the namespace in which `SomeFunction` is declared, you can use forward declaration of `Foo`. And in the header file where you define the class `Foo` you can actually `#include` the header file with the `SomeNamespace` and `SomeFunction` declarations.

Comment: I tried dividing header and cpp but I still get the same issue. I've updated the question a little with further details, if that might help.

I'm using a forward declaration in the declaration of the function; The header file where the function is declared is included in the file that contains the class. Also, the .cpp file where the function is defined #includes the class file.
But still, it seems like the function cannot access the class private members. "They inacessible"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comments, lets say you have the following three files:

- `Foo` header file

  ```
  #include "SomeNamespace.h"

  namespace X
  {
      class Foo
      {
          friend void SomeNamespace::SomeFunction(const Foo&);
      };
  }
  ```
- `SomeNamespace` header file

  ```
  namespace X
  {
      // Forward declaration
      class Foo;
  }

  namespace SomeNamespace
  {
      void SomeFunction(const Foo&);
  }
  ```
- `SomeNamespace` source file

  ```
  #include "SomeNamespace.h"
  #include "Foo.h"

  void SomeNamespace::SomeFunction(const Foo& foo)
  {
  }
  ```

<sub>[Note: Things like actual contents, as well as header include guards, purposefully omitted for brevity]</sub>

One of the header files needs to use forward declaration *only*, while the other can use `#include`.

The important part is that you must include all needed header files in the source file where you define (implement) the classes and functions.

Comment: Thanks. Unless I'm missing something, this is exactly what I'm doing. But apparently the private members can't be accessed nonetheless

Comment: Problem solved. Turns out I was missing a semicolon at the end of a previously-defined struct.

But this answer helped me fix the issue too, so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

s.hpp

```
#pragma once

class Foo; // forward declaration is enough here since you only use a reference

namespace SomeNamespace {
  void someFunction(const Foo& foo);
}
```

f.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "s.hpp"  // the function declaration of someFunction is needed

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int X);
    friend void SomeNamespace::someFunction(const Foo& foo);
private:
    int x;
};
```

s.cpp

```
#include "f.hpp"  // Foo's definition is needed here
#include "s.hpp"
#include <iostream>
namespace SomeNamespace {
  void someFunction(const Foo& foo) {
      std::cout << foo.x << '\n';     // private member now accessible
  }
}
```

f.cpp

```
#include "f.hpp"

Foo::Foo(int X) : x(X) {}
```